# Proof of that for all $v \in V, 0 \otimes v = 0$ in quantale $\mathcal{V} = (V, \leq, I, \otimes, \multimap)$

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading "An Invitation to Applied Category Theory, Seven Sketches in Compositionality" by Brendan Fong and David I. Spivak, and I'm not satisfied with the authors' solution to question 1 of Exercise 2.78. To be more spesific, I don't understand the part that proves that for all $v \in V, 0 \otimes v = 0$. The exercise and the solution are quoted below.

> **Exercise 2.78.** Let $\mathcal{V} = (V, \leq, I, \otimes, \multimap)$ be a quantale. Use Eq. (2.26) and Proposition 2.64 to do the following.
>
> 1. Prove the *identity law*: for any sets *X* and *Y* and *V*-matrix $M : X \times Y \to V$, one has $I_X * M = M$.
> 2. ...

> *Solution to* Exercise 2.78
>
> 1. We first use Proposition 2.64 (2) and symmetry to show that, for all $v \in V, 0 \otimes v = 0$,
>    $$0 \otimes v \cong v \otimes 0 \cong \left(v \otimes \bigvee_{a \in \varnothing} a\right) = \bigvee_{a \in \varnothing} (v \otimes a) = 0.$$
>    Then we may just follow ...

I have four questions about the above equation.

1. $\otimes$ is assumed to be symmetry (Definition 2.1). Why is the leftmost $\cong$ not $=$ ?
2. $\bigvee_{a \in \varnothing} a$ is definition of 0 ($0 := \bigvee \varnothing$). Why is the seccond $\cong$ from the left not $=$ ?
3. In Proposition 2.64, the fact that $\otimes$ distributes over joins is represented by $\cong$ instead of $=$. Why is it represented by $=$ in the solution?
4. $V$ is preorder, not poset, so $A \cong B$ doesn't necessarily mean $A = B$. Why can we draw the conclusion $0 \otimes v = 0$ ?

P.S.
I'm reading the book (e-book) version, which apparently differs from the PDF version in the numbers assigned to exercises, formulas, etc. What I am stuck with is Exercise 2.104 in the PDF version (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05316.pdf).

Comment: (Last updated: October 16, 2018)

Comment: @JoelSjögren huh?

Comment: Are you saying it's this version? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05316.pdf The copy I have saved, I was getting different proposition numbers.

Comment: @river I'm reading the book (e-book) version, which apparently differs from the PDF version in the numbers assigned to exercises, formulas, etc. What I am stuck with is Exercise 2.104 in the PDF version (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05316.pdf).
I'll add this information to the question text.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I meant to imply that the asker should use this version, which is the newest one I could find.